# MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js

I am trying to integrate with [DyDx Protocol](https://dydxprotocol.github.io/v3-teacher/?typescript#keypairwithycoordinate), and trying to perform some action on the PrivateAPI:

```
const client: DydxClient = new DydxClient(
                        DYDX_HOST,
                        {
                            networkId: 5,
                            web3: new Web3(window.ethereum),
                        },
                    );
```

and calling the APICredentials call, it is failing:

```
client.onboarding.recoverDefaultApiCredentials(
                        address,
                    ).then((response) => {
                        console.log("response for api keys", response)
                    });
```

Below is the error:

```
"{
  "code": -32602,
  "message": "Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.",
  "stack": "Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.\n    at new r (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:322950)\n    at i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:325706)\n    at Object.invalidParams (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:326213)\n    at p (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:10:31397)\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:10:29445\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:38021\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:38404\n    at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:37125\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at a._runMiddleware (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:36782)\n    at a._runAllMiddleware (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:36688)\n    at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:35360"
}
  at new r (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:322950)
  at i (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:325706)
  at Object.invalidParams (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-2.js:1:326213)
  at p (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:10:31397)
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background-0.js:10:29445
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:38021
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:38404
  at chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:37125
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at a._runMiddleware (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:36782)
  at a._runAllMiddleware (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:36688)
  at async chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/common-6.js:19:35360"
```

I have already tried to convert the GoreliaTestNet address to checkSum:

```
const address = Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(accounts[0]);
```

But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, had to add the signing method.

```
client.onboarding.recoverDefaultApiCredentials(
                        address,SigningMethod.MetaMask
                    ).then((response) => {
                        console.log("response for api keys", response)
                    });
```